# Adding a bootstrap-switch (with an icon) dynamically but not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap-switch (http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/), and I want to use icons instead of texts for switchs; What I'm addding is added dynamically by an ajax call and .HTML attribute; I have tried the following code which is passed by the HTML attribute but instead of showing the icon, it is showing

```
<span class='icon-remove'></span>
```

My code:

```
<input type='checkbox' checked id='chkAll_tab3' name='chkAll_tab3' class='switch switch-success' data-label-on=\"<span class='icon-remove'></span>\" data-label-off='Archieve' />
```

Do you know how I can fix it?

If you need more clarification, please let me know!

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

to the latest versions :

```
<input class="make-switch" type="checkbox" data-on-text="<i class='fa fa-unlock'></i>" data-off-text="<i class='fa fa-lock'></i>"/>
```

for the old versions :

```
<input class="make-switch" type="checkbox" data-on-label="<i class='fa fa-unlock'></i>" data-off-label="<i class='fa fa-lock'></i>"/>
```

init bootstrapSwitch

```
<script>
 $(".make-switch").bootstrapSwitch();
</script>
```

Comment: nice. I guess the documentation hasn't been updated. http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/documentation-2.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is easy and best concept to implement UI of checkbox and radio with Bootstrap... No need to do more just use below code to implement:

```
  <div class="checkbox">
                    <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
                    <label for="checkbox1">
                        Default
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                    <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" checked="">
                    <label for="checkbox2">
                        Primary
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
                    <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox">
                    <label for="checkbox3">
                        Success
                    </label>
                </div>
```

Add Custom css in your css file which is bootstrap based :

```
     .checkbox {
  padding-left: 20px; }
  .checkbox label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 5px; }
    .checkbox label::before {
      content: "";
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      width: 17px;
      height: 17px;
      left: 0;
      margin-left: -20px;
      border: 1px solid #cccccc;
      border-radius: 3px;
      background-color: #fff;
      -webkit-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
      transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out; }
    .checkbox label::after {
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      margin-left: -20px;
      padding-left: 3px;
      padding-top: 1px;
      font-size: 11px;
      color: #555555; }
  .checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    opacity: 0; }
    .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label::before {
      outline: thin dotted;
      outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
      outline-offset: -2px; }
    .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
      font-family: 'FontAwesome';
      content: "\f00c"; }
    .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
      opacity: 0.65; }
      .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label::before {
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        cursor: not-allowed; }
  .checkbox.checkbox-circle label::before {
    border-radius: 50%; }
  .checkbox.checkbox-inline {
    margin-top: 0; }

.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  background-color: #428bca;
  border-color: #428bca; }
.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  color: #fff; }

.checkbox-danger input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  background-color: #d9534f;
  border-color: #d9534f; }
.checkbox-danger input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  color: #fff; }
```

I hope this will help you to do more write less :-) More example you can find by click at this link : http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/ZkMKE

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `div` instead of `input`

Have you considered http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/#html-text-label-icon?

```
<div class="make-switch switch-large" data-label-icon="icon-fullscreen" data-on-label="<i class='icon-ok icon-white'></i>" data-off-label="<i class='icon-remove'></i>">
```