# bootstrap glyphicon with bootstrap switch

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [bootstrap-switch](https://github.com/Bttstrp/bootstrap-switch) with bootstrap v3.

I want to use an icon for the text to display on the switch.

If i use font awesome icons like this it works.
[using font awesome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNljQ.png) 
[using font awesome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdneT.png) 
and here is the code:

```
$("[name='pets_check_box']").bootstrapSwitch('onText', '<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
$("[name='pets_check_box']").bootstrapSwitch('offText', '<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
```

and if i use bootstrap glyphicon the icon is not displayed...
[using bootstrap glyphicon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flmIR.png)
[using bootstrap glyphicon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9xsj.png)
here is the code:

```
$("[name='pets_check_box']").bootstrapSwitch('onText', '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>');
$("[name='pets_check_box']").bootstrapSwitch('offText', '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>');
```

When I’m using glyphicon without bootstrap-switch the glyphicon is working properly. 
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I also use $('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]').data("off-text", "<i class='glyphicon .glyphicon-glyphicon-remove-circle'></i>"); and is not working. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200151/adding-a-bootstrap-switch-with-an-icon-dynamically-but-not-working

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Bootstrap(>= v4.0) will not support the glyphicon icons. In the official site they have mentioned, If you need icons, some options are:

- the upstream version of Glyphicons
- Octicons
- Font Awesome

Find below link for reading the detailed information.

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#components

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have include bootstrap.css and  bootstrap.css has below entry

```
.glyphicon-ok:before {  content: "\e013";}
```

Comment: I included bootstrap.css and it has the entry... Thanks!